Remove the 'resetting any rude or abusive flags' note from the rollback tooltip
The tooltip for the rollback button in a revision history is:

sets the current revision to this version of the post, resetting any "rude or abusive" flags

However, the 'resetting of red flags' when performing a rollback seems to have been removed/not exist. Additionally, references to this behavior in the rollback FAQ has been removed.
Can this tooltip be updated or clarified?

If anyone's looking into this, see the comments on the first post the author linked for more context.
